# which is better, "Install ubuntu alonside windows" or "something else"

Tags: software-recommendation

i just downloaded the latest version of ubuntu (14.04) and before im doing the installation through USB i want to know, which way is better; i already have a win7 SO and want to keep it, i saw a lot of tutorials but mostly of them tell me to do manually for the partitions.

why they prefer in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see a tutorial suggesting manual repartitioning for a *simple* alongside install, it's probably from the 80s and you should back away slowly before thoroughly ignoring it.

[image]

Don't get me wrong, you can spend hours repartitioning everything manually if you want to or if you have particularly odd requirements, but it's going to be doing exactly the same thing as the installer, only I trust the installer more than a human not to make a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As Oli suggests use the latest Ubuntu USB installer to avoid silly errors. I would suggest you do this with a USB stick that has around 4GB space on it.

Comment: i tried to install alongside and the program take space from C:/

but the route (dev/sda2) confuse me since i already have another partition NTFS (D:/ just backup archives) and it haves the same route (dev/sda2) there's gonna be problems if both partitions (the ex4 and the D:/) have this same route?

Comment: Have you tried the "try ubuntu" option? is it running?. After this installation you describe which takes space from your hard drive - what happens when you reboot?. Are you able to provide more specific errors that come up?. I would suggest you try and search for the specific error as it comes when installing - that way, you will understand what is going on.

Comment: im the "try ubuntu" option at this moments and looks very nice, when i tried to install it alongside it takes space from C/, that's where my windows is and i can browse both partitions from here